# BTRFS scrub doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: btrfs

One of my drives is exhibiting read failures:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
[...]
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11729         3678402408
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11729         3678402408
[...]
```

This is preventing me from removing it as a device from the filesystem it's a part of:

```
$ sudo btrfs device remove /dev/mapper/cryptsdd1 /
ERROR: error removing device '/dev/mapper/cryptsdd1': Input/output error
```

So, I'm trying to scrub it to find the affected files (I don't think scrub will repair anything as I'm not using a redundant-data RAID configuration). But, scrub doesn't seem to do anything.

```
$ sudo btrfs scrub start /dev/mapper/cryptsdd1
```

Doesn't produce any output and doesn't return. Opening another terminal and using status doesn't return either. I'm also unable to terminate either of these processes.

What's going on with scrub here and how can I resolve it?

My ultimate goal is to replace this problematic HDD with a good one. I *think* all data I care about is safe and I suspect the problematic files are in an old snapshot of my home directory. To provide some background, I snapshot my home directory every hour and then backup the snapshot to a set of backup disks. I've been able to perform snapshots fine and I've also been able to backup these snapshots to a remote backup service. However, I noticed the IO error when backing up to the local backup disks (for a reason I won't get into, the local backups ended up being far behind the remote backups). This involved an old snapshot (the problematic disk is used for my root filesystem, not backup disks). If I lose data from this old snapshot I don't care. Thoughts on how to remove this disk gracefully would be greatly appreciated.

I'm on Linux 5.12.4.

Happy to post further information - just let me know.

Comment: First *verify* that all the data you care about is actually safe. Manually.

Comment: Then I'd recommend you to ddrescue the disk somewhere (either another disk/partition or into an image file), unplug the original and try to remove the clone.

Comment: Any ideas for how to verify the data I care about? That spans a ton of files.

Comment: Easiest is making another copy/backup. Through other means than filesystem snapshots preferably. Have a look through them and verify they're what you expect them to be. I.e. look at files you've modified recently.

Comment: If that all doesn't work, unplug the drive, mount degraded + readonly(!) and see what data has become inaccessible by doing that. It's likely more than just a few old snapshots.

Comment: Thanks @Atemu. I checked a few recently-edited files and they all looked ok. ddrescue reported 99.99% of data rescued (with 2 bad sectors). I think if recent data had been affected than backing up the snapshot to a remote backup service would have caused similar I/O errors, which it didn't. I've now removed the problematic drive and replaced it with a good one.